Must a man first be a priest before being consecrated a bishop?
Must a man first be a priest before being consecrated a bishop?
In other words: Who exactly can receive episcopal consecration?

Are you asking ontologically or canonically? Your answer covers the canonical angle.

@eques Does skipping orders or not observing the interstitial times invalidate the orders received or only make their reception illicit? I would like to know historically, too. Do you know?

I'm fairly certain that a man to be ordained a bishop, even in extraordinary circumstances, must first be ordained a priest. Though in extraordinary circumstances, he could be ordained a priest and then a bishop immediately afterwards.

@Geremia I'm fairly certain that while ordination does pertain to a juridical state, unlike marriage, changeable law doesn't affect validity.

Yes. He must be priest for at least 5 years before being consecrated a bishop:

Can. 378 §1. In regard to the suitability of a candidate for the episcopacy, it is required that he is:
[…]
4/ ordained to the presbyterate for at least Five years;

(1917 CIC canon 331 is substantially the same.)
Also, 1917 CIC can. 977 prohibits skipping orders:

Orders are to be conferred by steps, so that ordination all at once is prohibited.

And interstitial times are to be observed.
cf. Doronzo, De ordine (t. 3): De causis extrinsecis, § VII. Susceptio ordinis inferioris & § VIII. Interstitia, pp. 567-9.

St. Ambrose was made a bishop only 8 days after his baptism, so the law of the Church regarding interstitial times has changed.
